# Is $x^3$ in the null space of the transformation $p(x) \mapsto xp(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $h: P_3 \to P_4$ be given by $p(x) \mapsto xp(x)$.

Is $x^3$ in the null space ? Or is it in the range space ?

**Also**, I am having difficulty finding the null space and the range of this map, can someone direct me please?

What I think: N space : $$\{ a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 |  z  + ax + bx^2 + cx^3 + dx^4 = 0 + 0x + 0x^2 + 0x^3 + 0x^4\}$$

I am not sure if I should have the $z$. I added it in because with $P_4$ I thought I should have 5 terms. Or should i leave it out and since the transformation multiplies $xp(x)$ which will cause an entry with $x^4$ and this will satisfy the $P_4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null space is trivial. Indeed, if $p$ is a nonzero, its leading coefficient is nonzero. And what is the leading coefficient of $xp(x)$? Same thing.

As for $x^3$ being in the range... can you factor $x^3=x\cdot (?)$. Yes...

More generally, every polynomial from which you can pull out the factor of $x$ is in the range. Whether or not you can do this depends on the free term $a$.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Is the Range R(T) = ax + ax^3 + a^x3 ?

Comment: The range is $\{ax+bx^2+cx^3+dx^4\}$, which is probably what you tried to type. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).